# Url encode a dot (.) in URL?

Tags: php, symfony1

Currently I am doing a small code in symfony that will cause url have resource like this:

```
http://url/val/abc.abxhd
```

I was able to get the parameter abc successfully from `http://url/val/abc`, but when I try to run the URL of `http://url/val/abc.abxhd`. Symfony simply throw a 404 error.

What could be the problem here. the URl are written using rawurlencode also.

```
group:
  url: /group/:group
  param: {module: group, action: show}
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get]
```

Comment: can you show your relevant routing config (`routing.yml`)

Comment: As I know in Php you can pass parameters following with `?` question mark symbol like this `http://url/val/?abc.abxhd`

Comment: I just add the route to my question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually symfony was finding dot (.) as a segment separator. This is the reason why in my case it cannot find the route. After Add the ff to my route. it works just like expected:

```
group:
  url: /group/:group
  param: {module: group, action: show}
  requirements:
    sf_method: [get]
  options:
    segment_separators: [/]
```

Comment: glad you eventually found an answer to your own question. You can also accept it to close the topic :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like **Symfony doesn't like dots** `.` in urls : http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/65d928b601bff9f4/096af0fcc478997b?pli=1

Users provide several tips and solutions.

What you can do is to handle this with [**url rewriting**](http://www.librosweb.es/symfony_1_0_en/capitulo9/url_rewriting.html) (as suggested in the thread) but take care not to rewrite files (meaningly: `http://url/folder/myjquery.js`)

Comment: Couldn't understand why I still have problem after try their .htaccess file? `Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL "/group/abc.xyzsds" (/).`