# Symfony 1.4 require a domain name in routing

Tags: php, symfony1, url-routing

I need to require a domain name in my symfony routing, my route looks like the following:

```
domain_example:
url: /routing/example/:domain_name
param: { module: myModule, action: index, sf_format: json }
requirements: { domain_name: '/^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}$/' }
```

I have also tried:

```
requirements: { domain_name: '[/^[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}$/]' }
```

If I call my route like so: `mydomain.com/routing/example/otherdomain.com` - I just get the module/action does not exist exception.

Comment: Is this useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010630/url-encode-a-dot-in-url?

Comment: And this one for the regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1129242/569101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To summarize*

dot are used [as segment separator](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/routing/sfPatternRouting.class.php#L49) in Symfony. So you should add this option to your route to force Symfony to only use `/` as separator:

```
  options:
    segment_separators: [/]
```

Next, your regex is wrong, but SO [has one for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129242/569101):

```
[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?
```

Your final route:

```
domain_example:
  url: /routing/example/:domain_name
  param:
    module: main
    action: index
    sf_format: json
  requirements:
    domain_name: '[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?'
  options:
    segment_separators: [/]
```